# Why are templates and template specializations entities and classes are not?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to the standard §6/p3 [basic]:

> An entity is a value, object, reference, structured binding, function,
>   enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template
>   specialization, namespace, or parameter pack.

Got a naive question. Since templates are "the blueprints for a class", Why templates and template specializations are considered entities and classes are not? Or I'am missing something?

Comment: A class is a type, isn't it?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen would be more accurately to write template partial specializations, since template specializations are also types?

Comment: Function template specializations are not types I think (they are functions though). Then there are variable templates, and templated `using`, but I suppose they are covered too.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes I think those are covered in the general term template.

Comment: I was referring to their specializations, but those are also covered. So I suppose you can say there is some redundancy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are included in the list because classes are types.

Comment: Standard justification: §12 Classes [class]/p1 A class is a type...